# Display page excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code to list a set of pages on my website.
Along with the `title`, I'd like to show an `excerpt` from the page.
How would I modify my code to allow this?

```
$children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=" . $parent . "&echo=0&depth=1&exclude=".$post->ID);

if ($children) {
?>

    <ul class="subnav">
        <?php 
            echo $children;
        ?>
    </ul>

<?php 
}
```

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have done something like this :

```
var $args = array(
    'post_parent'=>$parent,
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID),
    'post_type' => 'page'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if($query->have_posts())
{
    echo "<ul>";
    while($query->have_posts())
    {
        $query->the_post();
        echo "<li>".get_the_title()."<br/>".get_the_excerpt()."</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the function wp_list_pages is messing that up try to check that

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?php 
// Gets all existing pages and their data (filters can be applied as well)
$pages = get_pages();

// Loops over all pages
foreach($pages as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post); 
    the_title();
    the_excerpt();
}
?>
```

For more information about the get_pages filters take a look at: [get_pages()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)

To edit the excerpts length and the more text you could use this functions:

```
<?php
function custom_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 20;
}

function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    return '...';
}

add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the use the wp excerpt function

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

**Doc:**
**[Excerpt function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt)**